# Global configuration in Spring annotational transactions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, spring-annotations

We use Spring transactions using annotational @Transactional attribute instead of XML alternative. Is it possible to specify some service methods as "read-only" as declared in XML version?

As far as I know, in XML version, you can specify methods and read-only configurations as:

```
      <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="*"/>
      </tx:attributes>
```

But I want to use this configurations in annotational services. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can translate that xml to `@Transactional`. That annotation is to be placed on methods and/or classes and the usage is different. You need to think differently: for example, if you have a class with many `get*` methods then you place a `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` at class level and then for each method you don't want to be readOnly you place another `@Transactional(readOnly=false)`. Also, you can place `@Transactional` on interfaces and if you can create interfaces common for many classes you can define the transactional behavior in one place: in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can translate that xml to `@Transactional`. That annotation is to be placed on methods and/or classes and the usage is different.

You need to think differently: for example, if you have a class with many `get*` methods then you place a `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` at class level and then for each method you don't want to be `readOnly` you place another `@Transactional(readOnly=false)`. Also, you can place `@Transactional` on interfaces and if you can create interfaces common for many classes you can define the transactional behavior in one place: in the interface.

Comment: Thanks Andrei.
One of related questions, it says, it can be done. Check link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669329/spring-transactions-mixing-transactional-with-txadvice-into-a-custom-annot?rq=1) But unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Unfortunately your proposal does not work for me. Because we have already hundreds of service classes and methods. Thanks again